# Add text to image animated with matplotlib ArtistAnimation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have several images as 2d arrays and I want to create an animation of these images and add a text that **changes** with the image.

So far I managed to get the animation but I need your help to **add a text to each of the images**.

I have a `for` loop to open each of the images and add them to the animation, and let say that I want to add the image number (`imgNum`) to each of the images.

Here is my code that is working to generate a movie of the images, without text.

```
ims = []
fig = plt.figure("Animation")
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

for imgNum in range(numFiles):
    fileName= files[imgNum]

    img = read_image(fileName)

    frame =  ax.imshow(img)          

    ims.append([frame])

anim = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=350, blit=True, repeat_delay=350)

anim.save('dynamic_images.mp4',fps = 2)

plt.show()
```

**So, how can I add to each of the images a text with `imgNum` ?**

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add text with [annotate](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_guide.html#plotting-guide-annotation) and add the `Annotation` artist to the list artists that you pass to [ArtistAnimation](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html). Here's an example based on your code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation 
import numpy as np

ims = []
fig = plt.figure("Animation")
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

for imgNum in range(10):
    img = np.random.rand(10,10) #random image for an example

    frame =  ax.imshow(img)   
    t = ax.annotate(imgNum,(1,1)) # add text

    ims.append([frame,t]) # add both the image and the text to the list of artists 

anim = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=350, blit=True, repeat_delay=350)

plt.show()
```